# EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase complaining about locked database

Tags: neo4j, readonly

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Database locked.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:289)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:227)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase.java:54)
    at QueryNodeReadOnly.main(QueryNodeReadOnly.java:55)
```

This is using 1.8.2 version of neo4j. I've written a program that opens the db in readonly mode, querying and and make it sleep for a while before exiting.

## Here is the relevant text

```
 graphDb = new EmbeddedReadOnlyGraphDatabase( dbname); // Line 55 - the exception.
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
    if(sleepVal > 0)
    Thread.sleep(sleepVal);
```

I reckon I should not be getting this error. There are only 2 processes that open the db , both in read-only mode. In fact, it should work even if i open the db when another process has opened it to write to it.

Answer (score 3):

We disallow two databases accessing the same files on disk at the same time - even in read-only mode.

The reason being is that while we do not allow you to modify the database in read-only mode, Lucene will still write to disk when servicing your read requests, and having two instances access those same index files leads to race conditions and index corruptions.

Why is it you want 2x instances accessing the same files at the same time anyway? What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make multiple connections to an embedded database. Maybe you should consider using the REST server.